# Different css background for each div in prevAlll()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following on from my original (now answered) question here:
[Dont update multiple divs on hover events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35099020/dont-update-multiple-divs-on-hover-events/35099091#35099091)

JS:

```
$(function() {
 var scaletext = {
  1: 'SA',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'N',
  4: 'Da',
  5: 'SDa'
}
$('.scale').hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prevAll('.scale').addBack().css('background-color', 'yellow');
  $this.siblings('.scale-text').html(scaletext[$this.data('scale')]);
}, function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.prevAll('.scale').addBack().css('background-color', '');
   $this.siblings('.scale-text').html("No Rating");
 });
});
```

HTML

```
<table>
 <thead>
<tr>
  <td>Overall</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 1</td>
    <td width="300px">
    <div class="scale-text">No Rating</div>
    <div data-scale="1" class="scale scale-1"></div>
    <div data-scale="2" class="scale scale-2"></div>
    <div data-scale="3" class="scale scale-3"></div>
    <div data-scale="4" class="scale scale-4"></div>
    <div data-scale="5" class="scale scale-5"></div>
  </td>
  <td>Comment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Question 1</td>
  <td width="300px">
    <div class="scale-text">No Rating</div>
    <div data-scale="1" class="scale scale-1"></div>
    <div data-scale="2" class="scale scale-2"></div>
    <div data-scale="3" class="scale scale-3"></div>
    <div data-scale="4" class="scale scale-4"></div>
    <div data-scale="5" class="scale scale-5"></div>
  </td>
  <td>Comment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Question 1</td>
  <td width="300px">
    <div class="scale-text">No Rating</div>
    <div data-scale="1" class="scale scale-1"></div>
    <div data-scale="2" class="scale scale-2"></div>
    <div data-scale="3" class="scale scale-3"></div>
    <div data-scale="4" class="scale scale-4"></div>
    <div data-scale="5" class="scale scale-5"></div>
  </td>
  <td>Comment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Question 1</td>
  <td width="300px">
    <div class="scale-text">No Rating</div>
    <div data-scale="1" class="scale scale-1"></div>
    <div data-scale="2" class="scale scale-2"></div>
    <div data-scale="3" class="scale scale-3"></div>
    <div data-scale="4" class="scale scale-4"></div>
    <div data-scale="5" class="scale scale-5"></div>
  </td>
  <td>Comment</td>
</tr>
```

Currently each div will get a yellow background on hover. How would I get each div in the scale to have a different background color on hover?

Comment: why don't you use css for hover? and what other color you want? it's not clear

Comment: I will need to do click events anyway, JS seems like the way to go. The previously linked answer does a good job of doing the highlighted scale I was after. Ideally I'd like to start the scale with a red, and then progress up the scale dark orange, light orange yellow, green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating an array containing colors to be applied , using `.each()` to set `background` of each `.scale` element

```js
$(function() {
 var scaletext = {
  1: 'SA',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'N',
  4: 'Da',
  5: 'SDa'
};
  
var colors = ["red", "darkorange", "orange", "yellow", "green"];
  
$('.scale').hover(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.prevAll('.scale').addBack().each(function(i) {
    $(this).css("background", colors[i])
  })
  $this.siblings('.scale-text').html(scaletext[$this.data('scale')]);
}, function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.prevAll('.scale').addBack().css('background-color', '');
   $this.siblings('.scale-text').html("No Rating");
 });
});
```

```css
td > div.scale {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <thead>
<tr>
  <td>Overall</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Question 1</td>
    <td width="300px">
    <div class="scale-text">No Rating</div>
    <div data-scale="1" class="scale scale-1"></div>
    <div data-scale="2" class="scale scale-2"></div>
    <div data-scale="3" class="scale scale-3"></div>
    <div data-scale="4" class="scale scale-4"></div>
    <div data-scale="5" class="scale scale-5"></div>
  </td>
  <td>Comment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Question 1</td>
  <td width="300px">
    <div class="scale-text">No Rating</div>
    <div data-scale="1" class="scale scale-1"></div>
    <div data-scale="2" class="scale scale-2"></div>
    <div data-scale="3" class="scale scale-3"></div>
    <div data-scale="4" class="scale scale-4"></div>
    <div data-scale="5" class="scale scale-5"></div>
  </td>
  <td>Comment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Question 1</td>
  <td width="300px">
    <div class="scale-text">No Rating</div>
    <div data-scale="1" class="scale scale-1"></div>
    <div data-scale="2" class="scale scale-2"></div>
    <div data-scale="3" class="scale scale-3"></div>
    <div data-scale="4" class="scale scale-4"></div>
    <div data-scale="5" class="scale scale-5"></div>
  </td>
  <td>Comment</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Question 1</td>
  <td width="300px">
    <div class="scale-text">No Rating</div>
    <div data-scale="1" class="scale scale-1"></div>
    <div data-scale="2" class="scale scale-2"></div>
    <div data-scale="3" class="scale scale-3"></div>
    <div data-scale="4" class="scale scale-4"></div>
    <div data-scale="5" class="scale scale-5"></div>
  </td>
  <td>Comment</td>
</tr>
```