# prevAll including first element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am currently working on a script for a five star rating system.  I have a line of 5 fontawesome star icons.  When the mouse is hovered over a star, that star and the stars behind it should become full stars instead of empty stars.  I am currently using prevAll to apply the changes to the stars, but it doesn't work for the first star... assuming because if it's the first star, there's no 'prev' stars to apply to prevAll().  Also, when I take the mouse away from the stars, I want to return them to their original state, but when I set the html in the mouseout method, it erases them.  Is there a better way to do this?  Is there a workaround that I am not thinking of?  Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4uu8sqx6/) to demonstrate.  Thanks for your time.

```
<div class="rating">
  <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
</div>


$('.rating').each(function() {
    $element = $(this);
  console.log(originalStars);
  $(this).find('[class*="fa-star"]').each(function() {
    console.log('star icon found.');
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        var stars = $(this).prevAll().length;
        $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o');
          $(this).addClass('fa-star');
        });
        $(this).nextAll().each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('fa-star');
          $(this).addClass('fa-star-o');
        });
      });
  });
  var originalStars = $element.html();  
  $element.mouseleave(function(){
    $element.html(originalStars);
    console.log('mouse left element');
  });
});
```

Update:  Managed to get the original stars restored on mouseleave, but once that happens, the hover effects no longer apply.  I have updated the jquery here and in the jsfiddle.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35107499/different-css-background-for-each-div-in-prevalll/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the simple thing what you can do..

```
var originalStars = $('.rating').html();
$('.rating').on('mouseover','i[class*=" fa-star"]',function(){
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).closest('.rating').html(originalStars)
})
```

Attach `mouseover` and `mouseout` event to `i` elements which contains `class-fa-star` and also follow `event delegation` here since you are attaching elements dynamically to `div.rating` by replacing its `html` i.e. `event delegation` by attaching event to `div.rating`

**[Single Rating DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4uu8sqx6/14/)**

---

***Update for multiple rating functionality***

```
$('.rating').each(function(){
    var _parent=$(this);
    var originalStars = _parent.html();
    $(_parent).on('mouseover','i[class*=" fa-star"]',function(){
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(_parent).html(originalStars)
    })
})
```

**[Multiple rating DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4uu8sqx6/13/)**